# Undirected graph whose BFS and DFS trees have roots of degree 2

Tags: graphs, spanning-trees

> Draw a graph on $5$ vertices that satisfies all of the following conditions:
>
> 1. $G$ is an undirected connected graph.
> 2. For every node $v∈V$, in the spanning tree received by BFS($v$), $\deg v=2$.
> 3. For every node $v∈V$, in the spanning tree received by DFS($v$), $\deg v=2$.

I was trying to draw many graphs but none of them satisfied all of the conditions.

I was also trying to disprove that such a graph exists, but couldn't find any strong claim that I could use for my proof.

Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Try to prove that there exists a unique graph satisfying conditions 1 and 2. This graph doesn't satisfy condition 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The degree of the root in a BFS tree equals the degree of the vertex in the original graph. Hence condition 2 states that your graph is 2-regular. Since it is connected, it must be a 5-cycle. Running DFS on the 5-cycle results in a path, and in particular, the root has degree 1.

This argument shows that there's nothing special about the number 5: the result remains true for *any* number of vertices.